# How to search both Users and Nodes simultaneously in drupal 7

Tags: search

I have a url for search nodes like **"?q=search/node/article/xyz"**
   and
  I have a url for search users like **"?q=search/user/xyz"**

now i want to search both at a time simultaneously so, what is the url for this 
  in drupal 7.

I have links for Search Like **"Article Search"**,  **"User Search"**, and  **"All Search"**,

I have url for both article and user but not for All Links that's the problem
  please help.

Comment: With Drupal core,  or even with Views, I don't think it will be possible without custom search. For advanced search features, solr is a viable solution.

Answer (score 1):

As AyeshK noted in the comments, you can't get this functionality with Drupal core (or even Views).

There are a couple of modules you can try though:

- [Search API multi-index](https://drupal.org/project/search_api_multi) (relies on [Search API](https://drupal.org/project/search_api))

  > This module is an addition to the Search API module which allows users to search on several indexes at once.
  >
  > When the module is enabled, you'll get a new Views base table where you can search all enabled Search API indexes at once. Performance might suffer, though, if not all indexes lie on the same Solr server (or other backend server that supports this feature).
  >
  > Please note that, since multi-index searches aren't supported explicitly by the Search API, most other Search API add-on functionality (facets, autocomplete, saved searches, search pages, etc.) won't work with searches created with this module.
- [Entity Backend Search](https://drupal.org/project/entity_backend_search) (in alpha)

  > This module enables highly customizable search pages for any entity type on a site for the editorial staff. It does not require any modules outside Drupal Core and is very easy to configure.

Comment: hi thanks but i can't add more module to extend my drupal site

Answer (score 0):

It can done without extra modules, sort of - by cheating in Views (Views being a necessary module for nearly any site). It's far too involved to show in an answer, but making a custom search block (form) that redirects to a Views page - the page is setup as a content search using a contextual filter, then as a header or footer, create a separate block view of users that uses the same contextual filter from the url.

Depending on your layout, it would then show say 10 pieces of content, and underneath, 10 users where the search criteria matched.

One problem in using Views for searches, is I believe it still uses = and not LIKE for searching, meaning that partial words won't be found - but I have heard of workarounds for that problem as well.

Comment: view dont have contextual filters for both users and content thanks.

Comment: that depends on what you want to search. If you can restrict it to say User Names, then it should be do-able. If you want to search through all fields of a profile, then no, you would have to use something else